# PHP file won't open in browser, only download

Tags: php, apache-http-server

I can't get .php files to run on my server. For example, I created a test file entitled "test.php" with the following content (only):

```
<?php
phpinfo() ;
?>
```

When I try to open this or other php files through a web browser, it tries to download them rather than run them. Responses to similar questions suggest that this issue means the server isn't set up to run php. I looked up how to enable php on the server and found that I am supposed to uncomment the line

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

in the httpd.conf in the etc/apache2 directory. However, when I checked that file, the above line was already uncommented. Is there some other thing I need to change to make php work correctly?

Comment: loading php isn't enough. you need to tell Apache that .php files should be fed through that module, e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856825/what-does-htaccess-with-line-addhandler-php5-script-php-do

Comment: when you open the downloaded file, does it contain the code above? Or does it contain the expected HTML result ?

Comment: It contains the code above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to add the handler for the PHP extension, so that the scripts are actually handled by the PHP module.

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

Comment: For those using php7. File `httpd.conf` in your `<IfModule mime_module>`  add this line -> `AddHandler php7-script .php`